# Using Paramiko SSH module with csv.reader?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, for-loop, paramiko

I am currently using the paramiko module to SSH into a list of IP addresses provided as a .csv file then push commands to those IPs.  To accomplish this, I am using the csv.reader() to open and read 100 rows of the file which is in the following format.

*Serial number, IP Address, MS, RM* (MS & RM are pieces of info correlated to IP address)

#### The Context

This is where Im using csv.reader() to open and read the file to then place information as a dictionary `keys`.

I then go to nest another dictionary within `keys` as `keys[row[0]]` to index IP address and other pieces of info as `ep_ip`,`ms_key` and `rm_key`.

```
option_dict = open('OptionKeyDict.csv','r')
reader= csv.reader(option_dict)

keys= {}

for row in reader:
    keys[row[0]]= {'IP':row[1],'MS': row[2],'RM': row[3]}

ep_ip = keys[row[0]]['IP']
ms_key= keys[row[0]]['MS']
rm_key= keys[row[0]]['RM']

command= 'xCommand SystemUnit OptionKey Add Key: '

multi_site= command + ms_key
remote_monitor= command + rm_key
```

Then I go on to introduce the Paramiko logic of the script to take the statements above and SSH into IP address, then execute the `multi-site` & `remote-monitor` commands.

```
for host in keys:
    host= ep_ip
    i = 1

    while True:
        print ("\nTrying to connect to %s (%i/2)" % (host, i))

        try:
           ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
           ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
           ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, timeout= 5)
           print ("\nConnected to %s" % host )
           connection_state = 1
           break

    if connection_state == 1:
        client_shell = ssh.invoke_shell()
        time.sleep(.4)
        client_shell.send(multi_site + "\n")
        time.sleep(.4)
        client_shell.send(remote_monitor + "\n")
```

So, running this works partially. The script successfully SSH then pushes the commands but it only uses the pieces of information from the last row (IP address, MS & RM) and runs 100 times as there are 100 rows in .csv.

I cant seem to have the script to start at the first row then work its way down each line to the 100th row.

Now that I got the context out of the way... (Sorry, new to StackOverflow)

#### The Question

What am I missing here that will enable this to happen? I feel its a simple adjustment that Im not seeing.

Any and all feedback would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `host` variable in `for host in keys:` loop at all.

And you can actually use the data as you read them straight away. It does not look like you need to collect the data to `keys` at all.

```
for row in reader:
    host = row[1]
    ms_key = row[2]
    rm_key = row[3]

    i = 1

    while True:
        print ("\nTrying to connect to %s (%i/2)" % (host, i))

        try:
           ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
           ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
           ssh.connect(
               host, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, timeout= 5)
           print ("\nConnected to %s" % host )
           connection_state = 1
           break

    if connection_state == 1:
        client_shell = ssh.invoke_shell()
        time.sleep(.4)
        client_shell.send(multi_site + "\n")
        time.sleep(.4)
        client_shell.send(remote_monitor + "\n")
```

*(btw, the `i` is never changed from its initial value of `1`)*

Comment: Thank you for the response Martin! I see what your saying. Looks like i took extra steps when I did not need to. 
Also good catch with 'i' value! Will make those changes.